# GUI cross-thread safety in .NET when reading but NOT updating DataGridView Control

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, datagridview, invokerequired

While there are a ton of questions/answers on SO regarding updating a GUI control from a worker thread using Control.Invoke, I haven't been able to get clarity on the topic of reading data from a control without updating it.

Example: I have a DataGridView on a Windows Form.  From a worker thread, I want to check the value of a particular cell on the DGV, but I do not need/want to update the value.  From a worker thread I call a method that takes as its only parameter a DataGridView object, and then the method examines a particular cell in the DataGridView but does not modify it, do I need to use .Invoke in this case?

Right now the code appears to run fine with no apparent warnings WITHOUT using .Invoke.  However, I'm unclear on whether this is a safe thing to do or not since it does NOT update the DGV but instead just looks at the DGV's cells without modifying any of them.

Can someone please shed some light on this?  I'm sorry if this is a duplicate question, but I couldn't find any other questions that focused on just reading a Control without updating/modifying it in a multi-threading situation.

Thanks.

Example method to be called from a worker thread:

```
    private DataGridViewRow getRowObject(DataGridView dgv)
    {
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgv.Rows)
        {
                if ((int)dgv[specialColumn, row.Index].Value == 100)                    
                return row;
        }
    }
```

Comment: In general when your background worker needs information from the UI to do its work you should get the information from the UI *before* you start the worker and then pass a copy of the information to the worker.  You should only pull form the UI within the worker if it's truly necessary to get information changed after the worker starts.

Comment: Thanks.  Understanding that this is not necessarily good coding practice, the question is geared toward developing a deeper level of understanding of what is safe and is not safe, as opposed to what is smart or not smart coding practice. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The absence of an InvalidOperationException does **not** prove thread-safety.  Winforms only performs the check for very specific member accesses.  It has to involve the Handle property, used in an underlying operating system call.  That will *never* happen in your code, the DataGridView doesn't obtain its data from Windows calls.

An obvious case where it will not be thread-safe is where you allow the user to continue editing the grid values.  You'll of course get an unpredictable value that's entirely un-synchronized with the thread execution.  You'll have to set the DataGridView.ReadOnly property to *true* to prevent this from happening.

Then it greatly matters how the DataGridViewCell obtains its value.  The non-obvious cases are the ones where it raises the CellValueNeeded event or when the grid is databound.  Now it entirely depends on whether *that* code is thread-safe.

Comment: To be clear, let's assume we don't care about whether or not the value we read is synchronized/accurate.  The question is really about whether or not we can safely read the value without "breaking" anything or getting a run-time exception.  It may be the case that we read a value that is inaccurate due to no synchronization, but will this ever produce a run-time exception due to being "unsafe" ?

Comment: You have this horribly backwards.  Exceptions are *good*, they tell you something went wrong.  What you have to be terrified of are unsynchronized accesses that *don't* generate an exception.  But just bad data and no way to find out that you are producing a junk result.  Restating: there is no Santa Claus here, you won't get an exception.

Answer (score 2):

It is not safe.

The controls, especially he dataGrid, will use Collection classes under the hood. They are not safe to read when other threads might edit.

Reading some properties (ie SelecteItem) will require a Handle and trigger the Cross-thread warning Exception.